# Using href link delete a row from database with java servlet and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I looked for answers on the internet and I don't understand the solutions offered so this is my last resort: basically I have a table and I want to add,delete and edit records. In the jsp my code is:

```
 <c:forEach items="${All}" var="p">
             <tr>
                 <td>${p.id}</td>
                 <td>${p.firstName}</td>
                 <td>${p.middleName}</td>
                 <td>${p.lastName}</td>
                 <td>${p.email}</td>
                 <td><a href="edit?id=${p.id}">Edit</a>
                 <a href="delete?id=${p.id}">Delete</a></td>

             </tr>
             </c:forEach>
```

But when I click delete it redirects me to a 404 status code and a link with delete?id=1. So how can I make the link go to my DeletePost servlet where I delete the row,then redirect to the page where the table is displayed?

EDIT:In my web application I am trying to delete a row in my database but it doesn't seem to work and I have tried to figure out why but I can't. Here is my dao class:

```
public class userDao  {

private SessionFactory factory, session;

public userDao(SessionFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

public void delete(long id){
    Session session1 = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<User> u = null;
    try {
        tx = session1.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session1.createQuery("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        System.out.println("aaaaa" + id);
        u = query.list();
        session1.delete(u.get(0));
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }

    } finally {
        session1.close();
    }

}
}
```

And in my servlet i have:

```
public class DeleteServlet extends HttpServlet{
userDao u = new userDao(new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory());
User a = new User();
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    System.out.println("asa");
    response.sendRedirect("/A1.2/home.jsp");
}


@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    String s = request.getParameter("id");
    long id = Long.parseLong(s);
    u.delete(id);

    response.sendRedirect("/A1.2/home.jsp");
}
}
```

I think the problem is in the dao because I tried to get a user from the database and I got the null pointer exception.

Comment: By using the URL of your Delete servlet instead of `delete` . How is the servlet defined and mapped to a url? Note that using a link (and thus a GET request) to delete is really not a good idea. A DELETE, or at least a POST, should be used. If the google bot ever indexes this page, it will navigate through every link, and thus delete everything.

Comment: Damn, it was so easy, thanks a lot! I am using POST in my form but I still see the id in the url, is that ok?

Comment: Not really. The id should be a hidden field of the form.

Comment: Edited so maybe someone could help me again please.

Comment: What you have there is a SQL query. Session.createQUery() expects an HQL query. Those two languages have similarities, but are different. And you don't need any query anyway. Just use Session.get() or Session.load(). Read the hibernate documentation.

Comment: I tried with Object u1 = session1.get(User.class, id); then session.delete(u1) but no success.